# How the Number series getting in Python?

Tags: python

Can anyone explain how Number series result getting , what is the calculation?

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k > 0):
    result =  k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(10)

Result 
1
3
6
10
15
21
```

Comment: Is that all it's printing? I'd expect it to show numbers up to 55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted is a Python function that uses recursion to calculate the sum of the first k natural numbers. Recursion means that the function calls itself with a smaller argument until it reaches a base case, where it returns a simple value.

The base case of this function is when k is 0, and the function returns 0. This means that the sum of the first 0 natural numbers is 0. The recursive case is when k is greater than 0, and the function returns k plus the result of calling itself with k-1. This means that the sum of the first k natural numbers is equal to k plus the sum of the first k-1 natural numbers.

For example, if we call `tri_recursion(10)`, the function will do the following steps:

- Check if `k` is greater than 0, which it is.
- Call itself with `k-1`, which is 9, and store the result in a variable called `result`.
- Add k, which is 10, to `result`, and print the new result.
- Return the new result.

The same process will happen for `tri_recursion(9)`, `tri_recursion(8)`, ..., `tri_recursion(1)`, until `tri_recursion(0)` is reached. At this point, the function will return 0 and stop calling itself.

Now, the previous calls can return their results. The last call before the base case was `tri_recursion(1)`, which returns `1 + 0 = 1`. Then `tri_recursion(2)` returns `2 + 1 = 3`. Then `tri_recursion(3)` returns `3 + 3 = 6`. And so on, until `tri_recursion(10)` returns `10 + 45 = 55`. The function prints each result before returning it, so we see the series of numbers: 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, ..., 55.

To visualize this process better, you can use a tool like Python Tutor: [Here's the link for your code.](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=def%20tri_recursion%28k%29%3A%0A%20%20if%28k%20%3E%200%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20%20k%20%2B%20tri_recursion%28k%20-%201%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28result%29%0A%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%200%0A%20%20return%20result%0A%0Aprint%28%22%5Cn%5CnRecursion%20Example%20Results%22%29%0Atri_recursion%2810%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score -1):

For every recursive call you have to add the value to the result and return the result or print the result.

Solution:

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  result = 0
  if(k > 0):
    result +=  k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
print(tri_recursion(10))
```

it will work fine
Thanks,